# How can I do editable GridView Template Cells TextBox?

Tags: c#, gridview

How can I do editable GridView Template Cells TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a command column and set `ShowEditButton="True" EditText="Edit" ButtonType="Link"`
2. In your template column use the ItemTemplate to describe what the columns should look like in non-edit mode using `<asp:Label runat="server" id="txtMyLabel" text='<%# Eval("MyFieldToDisplay") %>' />`
3. Use the EditTemplate of your column to display your edit control. ex.
   `<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtMyFieldToEdit" text='<%# Eval("MyFieldToEdit") %>' />`
4. Handle the GridView.OnEditing event as such

   `protected void myGridView_OnEditing(object sender, GridViewEditingEventArgs e)
   {
       myGridView.EditIndex=e.RowIndex;
   }`

I believe these are the right property/attribute names, but I'm typing off the top of my head...

you'll more than likely need to handle OnCancelEdit as well and enable the cancel button in your command column.