# How can I create Editable GridView like Spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I create Editable GridView like Spreadsheet? (On asp.net 2005)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847260/how-can-i-do-editable-gridview-template-cells-textbox

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate.. I recommend leaving this open.

Answer (score 1):

This article talks about the new GridView for ASP .Net 2.0:  [From DataGrid to GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163933.aspx)

Download the MSDNGridView Sample here:  GridView Examples for ASP .Net 2.0 ([http: //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx))

Here's another good article:  Extending the GridView Control ([http: //msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the DataGridView that's provided?

Comment: and in Web application I dont find DataGirdView